# VS Code Explorer side bar navigation

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

When I press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> I set focus on the explore file tree, and can now navigate my files with the arrow keys.

Enter should active the file but instead it activates the rename command that is normal associate with <kbd>F2</kbd>.

It works on windows but not on my macbook. I know how to create a custom key binding. but I can not find the command for activating a file in keybindings.json.

I am using [Parallels Desktop 12 for Mac](http://www.parallels.com) and know that it can cause keyboard binding issues. But I dont think it's the case here.

So do someone have a solution for this or know the command to activate in the keybindings.json file?

Answer (score 1):

Bind the `list.select` event to `enter` in your `keybindings.json`

```
{
    "key": "enter",
    "command": "list.select",
    "when": "listFocus"
}
```